# Don't close infoWindow on map clicked. (Google Map Android API V2)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

By default marker's infoWindow is closed when map is clicked. Does anyone know how I can disable this behavior?
I tried to override `onMapClicked` but it doesn't work...

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {

        //do nothing
        }

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it would be to keep a class variable that specifies the marker currently selected. You would set it in the onMarkerClick() method. Call it, say, currentMarker. Putting

```
currentMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

in the onMapClick() method should then do the trick.

Comment: Good idea! Just remember to check `if (currentMarker != null)`

Comment: Works great, thanks!  I personally was using info windows as labels, so I just called `showInfoWindow` on all the markers.  No flicker or anything.  Also, the question deserves an upvote ;)

Comment: That is a really stupid solution (not your fault it's the API designer who was apparently on drugs or something) but it works. Thank you!